# Interpretations of a sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Legend has it that this word comes from back in the day when there was an East City and a West City in China, you really had to head to either one for supplies/shopping.

It appears on my [grammar book](https://chinauniversities.com/blog/blogpost102).

This sentence seems a little weird to me. I think of two possible interpretations.

1. There is an "and" missing.

Legend has it that this word comes from back in the day when there was an East City and a West City in China, **and** you really had to head to either one for supplies/shopping.

2. I can read it as having a colon after "from".  The word comes from a story, ie "back in the day when..."

Legend has it that this word comes **from:**  back in the day when there was an East City and a West City in China, you really had to head to either one for supplies/shopping.

Which one do you think makes sense?

Comment: I agree. You can use a comma to separate two clauses but there is usually a word like "and", as you point out, or "but" after the comma. If I wrote that sentence, I would replace the comma with a semicolon instead of using "and" but that is a style issue.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks.  What about my second interpretation?  Is that possible?

Comment: The last sentence with a colon after the word "from" doesn't make sense. Even removing the colon makes the sentence look awkward. I would change that to "this word comes from the time when ...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a comma splice, two related sentences linked by a comma.  [Do you see what I did there?]

A comma splice is a minor error in written English. English teachers marking essays will mark it.  Most other people don't even notice it if they are not looking.  It can be fixed by inserting a conjunction, or using a semicolon instead of a comma.

Your second interpretation don't fix the comma splice, and it breaks the grammar of the first part. I would not use a colon at that point. It doesn't help.